# NodeJS (Express) + MongoDB + Angular stream a request

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, stream

I want to stream a MongoDB query in NodeJS because, in Angular, i have a chart and i want to update the data without making a refresh.
So far, this is my code (NodeJS):

```
exports.gettoday = function (request, response) {
  db.collection("nifi5", function (err, collection) {
    collection
      .aggregate([
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              minute: {
                $minute: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$created_at" } },
              },
              hour: {
                $hour: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$created_at" } },
              },
              day: {
                $dayOfMonth: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$created_at" } },
              },
              month: {
                $month: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$created_at" } },
              },
              year: {
                $year: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$created_at" } },
              },
            },
            avg: { $avg: "$value_temperature" },
          },
        },
      ])
      .stream()
      .toArray(function (err, items) {
        if (err) {
          response.statusMessage = {
            devMessage: err,
            clientMessage: "Unexpected error, try again latter",
          };
          response.send(response.statusMessage).end();
        }
        let tarray = { labels: [], data: [] };
        items.forEach((element) => {
          element.date = element._id.hour + ":" + element._id.minute;
          element.avg = Math.round(element.avg * 100) / 100;
        });
        items.sort(function (a, b) {
          return a.date < b.date ? -1 : 1;
        });

        items.forEach((element) => {
          tarray.labels.push(element.date);
          tarray.data.push(element.avg);
        });

        return response.json(tarray);
      });
  });
};
```

Angular:

```
 gettodaydata(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.baseURL}gettoday`).subscribe((data) => {

      this.data_line.push(...data.data);
      this.labels_line.push(...data.labels);
      this.isLineChartLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

Can u please help me streaming this controller and fetch the data in Angular to update my chart when new data comes do my database ?
Thank you all!

Answer (score -1):

You should give a try to socket.io, it creates a persistent connection and responds to events in real time.

Comment: I used MongoDb watch() and socket IO. Problem solved !